# UDP client is not synchronous with UDP server timing

Tags: linux, udp

I am sending UDP packets from server for every 100 msec, at UDP client when I checked 
     the frequency of reception it is not equal to 100 msec, sometimes it is much less such as 3 msec…10 msec.
     I know UDP client server is asynchronous, not whether it is good to check the frequency
     of reception at UDP client, or it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Sending messages over network is never meant to preserve time intervals. Packets may come to client with arbitrary time intervals including possibility of re-ordering (packet sent first arrives later than packet sent second). If transferred data is sensitive to described effects, there are some tricks to reduce delay dispersion influence e.g. [jitter buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter#Jitter_buffers) for audio and video traffic